# PHPExcel can't write

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm trying to write a new Excel using the class PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007 and using PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter() but with both of them I'm getting next error:

"Message: Argument 1 passed to PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007::__construct() must be an instance of PHPExcel, instance of PHPExcel_Worksheet given"

I don't know what it's wrong.

I was testing this outside project to check everything is fine using PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter() but, the same code (copy paste) is not working inside the project.

I can't understand nothing and I'm not getting any other message to understand what happen.

This is the code:

```
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

    $activeSheet = 0;
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex($activeSheet);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setShowGridlines(false);

    $objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
    $objWriter->setUseDiskCaching(true);

    //$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($obj, 'Excel2007');

    $objWriter->save('testExcel.xlsx');
```

Answer (score 0):

I was sending to the writer, the object with a method into the project.